# Excel function ? which one to use

Tags: excel, function, analysis

I have a colums
where it has values like

```
1,2,3,4,5 or 1,2  or 3,4 or 5 only (many rows)

i want to find/convert

   if value =1,2,3,4,5 then created new colum(Myname) -"TEXT1"
   if value = 1,2 then value of newly created colum = "TEXT2)
   if value=3,4 then value = "text3"
   if value = 5 then "text 4"
```

which excel functions I should be using ? or any pointers

Comment: Excel functions will not create columns, or move information.  They can however display, and calculate information in the cell they are in.  Therefore with your example text saying create column, you will be entering the world of VBA or other similar prg language.

Comment: It is difficult to understand precisely your problem. Provide an example, ideally in the form of a screenshot, of what you are trying to do showing some input and the corresponding output.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
=IF(A1="1,2,3,4,5","text-1",IF(A1="1,2","text-2",IF(A1="3,4","text-3",IF(A1=5,"text-4","not found"))))
```

use this  function to convert the data and if cell is common for all you can freeze it